# How to find the maximum's index?

Tags: java, arrays, max

I got this problem here. The index is int, but the program throws me double. I can't find the problem. There are a lot of geometric shapes, and they have center coordinates and the length of their side. I had to calculate the difference of the area and the circumstance, and then pick the largest number's index.

/Main class

```
package beadandó;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class Main {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Geom geom = new Geom();
        try {
            geom.read("input.txt");
            System.out.println(geom.MaxKiv());
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println("File not found!");
            System.exit(-1);
        } catch (InvalidInputException ex) {
            System.out.println("Invalid input!");
            System.exit(-1);
        }
    }
}
```

/getDifference

```
package beadandó;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public abstract class GeometricShape {
    private Point center;
    double length;
    private ArrayList<Double> difference;

    public GeometricShape( Point center, double length) {
        this.center = center;
        this.length = length;
        difference = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void setCenter(Point center) {
        this.center = center;
    }

    public void setLength(double length) {
        this.length = length;
    }

    public Point getCenter() {
        return center;
    }

    public double getLength() {
        return length;
    }

    public ArrayList<Double> getDifference() {
        return difference;
    }

    public abstract double doMath();
}
```

/MaxKiv is the maximum finder

```
package beadandó;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Geom {

    private final ArrayList<GeometricShape> geometricShapes;

    public Geom() {
        geometricShapes = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void read(String filename) throws FileNotFoundException, InvalidInputException {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename)));
        int number = sc.nextInt();
        while (sc.hasNext()) {
            GeometricShape geometricShape;
            int kind = sc.nextInt();
            double x = sc.nextDouble();
            double y = sc.nextDouble();
            Point center = new Point(x, y);
            double length = sc.nextDouble();
            switch (kind) {
                case 0:
                    geometricShape = new Circle(center, length);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    geometricShape = new Triangle(center, length);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    geometricShape = new Square(center, length);
                    break;
                case 6:
                    geometricShape = new Hexagon(center, length);
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new InvalidInputException();
            }
            geometricShapes.add(geometricShape);
        }
    }

    public double MaxKiv() {
        double max = 0;
        int index =0;
        for (int i = 0; i < geometricShapes.size(); ++i) {
            if (max <geometricShapes.get(i).doMath()) {
                max = geometricShapes.get(i).doMath();
                index=i;
            }
        }
        return index;
    }
}
```

/Calculate the differences (there are many shapes, this is one of them)

```
package beadandó;

import static java.lang.Math.sin;

public class Hexagon extends GeometricShape {

    public Hexagon(Point center, double length) {
        super(center, length);
    }

    @Override
    public double doMath() {        
        double circumfence=(3*(length*length)*sin(60));
        double district=(6*length);
        double difference=(circumfence-district);
        return difference;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do not ever design your question like this. Post your effort to get quick help.

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: I'm sorry. I posted the code.

Comment: I think that instead of this line: `index=1;` you want `index = i;`.

Comment: CodeMatrix edited the code to 1. It was i. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have declared:

```
public double MaxKiv() {
```

So yes, obviously this gives you a `double`. To get an `int` instead, simply change the declaration to return an `int`:

```
public int MaxKiv() {
```

The value you are returning, `index`, is already declared an `int`, so this should be enough fix your issue.